# Rendering user controls in EPIserver dynamic content

Tags: c#, episerver, dynamic-content

Im trying to make a EPIserver dynamic content control, the content i want is a user control which i already made(a slider), every thing seems to work just fine until i insert the dynamic content control onto the page/area i want to use it.

When i now go to the page i have created it displays the "static" content:

```
<h3>Dynamic slider</h3>
<TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTest" />
<cd:TopSlider runat="server" ID="MySlider"/>
```

out of these 3 items the header and the textbox is shown, but not the "cd:TopSlider",
and in the OnPageLoad i set the text in the TextBox to 'FooBar' but this is not displayed either, it seams it never goes server-side, I've tried to place breakpoints but non is triggered . . .

Here is the code for the DynamicContent files:

*The usercontrol which is loaded DynamicContentTest.ascx.cs:*

```
public partial class DynamicContentTest : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public IEnumerable<SliderPage> DataSource { get; set; }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            txtTest.Text = "FooBar";

            MySlider.DataSource = DataSource;
            MySlider.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

*DynamicContentTest.ascx:*

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cd" TagName="TopSlider" Src="~/UserControls/TopSlider.ascx" %>
<!-- Slider -->
<h3>Dynamic slider</h3>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTest" />
<cd:TopSlider runat="server" ID="mySlider"/>
<!-- END Slider -->
```

*DynamicContentControl:*

```
[DynamicContentPlugIn(
        DisplayName = "Dynamic slider",
        Description = "Displays a slider",
        ViewUrl = "~/UserControls/DynamicContent/Custom/DynamicContentTest.ascx")]
    public class DynamicSliderControl : UserControlBase
    {
        public PageReference SlidesRoot { get; set; }

        public System.Web.UI.Control GetControl(EPiServer.PageBase hostPage)
        {
            var userControl = (UserControls.DynamicContent.Custom.DynamicContentTest)hostPage.LoadControl("~/UserControls/DynamicContent/Custom/DynamicContentTest.ascx");
            userControl.DataSource = SlidesRoot != null ?
                SlidesRoot.GetChildrenOfType<SliderPage>() : null;
            return userControl;
        }

        public bool RendersWithControl
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public string State { get; set; }
    }
```

I used these articles as guide's:

[Create EPiServer dynamic content with advanced settings](http://tedgustaf.com/en/blog/2010/10/user-control-for-specifying-dynamic-content-settings-in-episerver/)

[Creating simple Dynamic Content in EPiServer CMS 6 R2](http://tedgustaf.com/en/blog/2011/4/creating-dynamic-content-in-episerver-cms-6-r2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using an EPiServer:Property control to render the dynamic content?

If you don't use this, EPiServer doesn't have chance to intercept the Dynamic Content and render it out appropriately.

Comment: No im not using that, is that something i should use ? Im somewhat new to EpiServer so haven used this before in any context. . .

Comment: I finally got around to testing this and it works, so i will accept this as an answer, but we use pagetype builder so we would still like to work around EPiServer:property.But Thank you for the answer it helped me narrow down the problem. PS: next time you answer someone you should be more specific, since that one line dint give me much to go by.

Answer (score 0):

> We use pagetype builder so we would still like to work around EPiServer:property

In that case, [this](http://tedgustaf.com/en/blog/2009/9/parse-an-episerver-xhtml-property-with-dynamic-content/) link may help you.